# Generic class create with new keyword

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have got a class. Its like that;

```
    public class AlarmSeverityDto
{
    private readonly DataRow _dr;

    public object this[string columnname] { get { return _dr[columnname]; } }
    public string Id { get { return Convert.ToString((_dr["Id"])); } }

    public string Description { get { return Convert.ToString((_dr["Description"])); } }

    public AlarmSeverityDto(DataRow dr)
    {
        _dr = dr;
    }
}
```

I use this class like that;

```
    public List<AlarmSeverityDto> GetAlarmSeverityDtos()
    {
        var resultList = new List<AlarmSeverityDto>();
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(_szConn))
        {
            var query = string.Format("SELECT Id, Description " +
                                      "FROM  tblAlarmSeverityType");

            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, connection);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow hbrow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        var alarmSeverityDto = new AlarmSeverityDto(hbrow);
                        resultList.Add(alarmSeverityDto);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

I want to make generic my GetAlarmSeverityDtos. But I cant do this with generic. I try that but i cant do one line. My Generic class like that;

```
 public List<T> GetDataTable<T>(string query) where T : class,new()
```

But what should i do wrrite for this line ?

```
var alarmSeverityDto = new AlarmSeverityDto(hbrow);
```

How can i write this line with generic class?

Comment: GetAlarmSeverityDtos this method will part of which class ?

Comment: you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` method and pass required parameters in constrcutor

Comment: like that ;
var alarmSeverityDto = Activator.CreateInstance(T);

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance`

Or another way (depending on your needs), you could use an interface

```
public interface IMyAwesomeInterface
{
    DataRow DataRow { get; set; }
}

...

public class AlarmSeverityDto : IMyAwesomeInterface

...

public List<T> GetAlarmSeverityDtos<T>() where T : IMyAwesomeInterface, new()
{
    ...
    var alarmSeverityDto = new T() { DataRow = hbrow};

    resultList.Add(alarmSeverityDto);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it wont fill my class property. Propertys are null.

Comment: @user1436795 take note i replaced `_dr` with  `DataRow DataRow { get; set; }`

Comment: thank you, its working fine for me. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a factory function that specifies how to convert data rows to T. For example:

```
public List<T> GetDataTable<T>(string query, Func<DataRow, T> factory )
```

Then within GetDataTable, create instances by calling the callback:

```
T record = factory(hbrow);
```

Finally GetDataTable can be called by passing a callback. E.g.:

```
List<AlarmSeverityDto> result = GetDataTable<AlarmSeverityDto>( query, 
row => new AlarmSeverityDto(row) );
```

This allows for the type variable to be of any type without needing to support a specific interface, and without having to rely on runtime activatation services.